# The value of the limit of a function

Tags: limits

The circled option is the answer I find but I'm not sure if I'm correct. Can someone please check this for me?

[image]

Comment: Checked: You did circle an option, as you say you did. Next question?

Comment: Ohh, and if you mean to check your work for you, you'll need to show the work you did that led you to circle the option you circled: by ***editing your post to show your work, and explain why you are uncertain about your work***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your answer is not correct. I would drop hints but as others have gave you a full solution, I'll try to go a bit slower than the other answers. Multiplying through the conjugate,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 3x} - x = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 3x}+x}$$

By the difference of two squares,

$$(\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x) = (\sqrt{x^2 + 3x})^2 - (-x)^2 = x^2+3x-x^2=3x$$

So we have,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {3x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 3x}+x}$$

From which we can factor $x$,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {3x}{x\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac 3 x} + 1\right)}$$

We therefore have,

$$3\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{1 + \frac 3 x} + 1}$$

Finally observe that,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac 1 x = 0$$

To evaluate,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 3x} - x = \frac 3 {\sqrt{1+0}+1} = \boxed{\frac 3 2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong.
$$\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x=\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x)}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x}=\frac{x^2+3x-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x}$$
$$\frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2(1+3/x)}+x}=\frac{3x}{x(\sqrt{1+3/x}+1)}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{1+3/x}+1}\to\frac{3}{2}$$
as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

write $$\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+3x}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x)}{\sqrt{x^2+3x}+x}$$